# Image drag glitchy on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built a quick block which allows someone to zoom in on an image and then drag (pan and zoom).

To do this, I have used panzoom:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  $("#panzoom").panzoom({
    $zoomRange: $(".zoom-range"),
    $reset: $(".reset"),
    contain: 'invert',
  });

});
```

```css
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 60px 20px;
  height: 600px;
}
.wrap .padding, section{
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.panzoom/2.0.6/jquery.panzoom.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  
  <div class="padding">
  
    <section>
      <div id="panzoom" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KhWo66L.png" width="100%">
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="buttons">
      <button class="reset">Reset</button>
      <input type="range" class="zoom-range">
    </section>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

The above works fine on desktop. But on mobile, since the user users the screen to scroll, when trying to drag the image across, it "stutters".

Difficult to explain, best demo'd on an actual device.

Any ideas on what the issue is here?

Comment: What is the mobile device and what is the size of the image in bytes?  Your HTML does not give the dimensions of the image so it must be whatever it is in the image, how big is the image?

Comment: Can you put a video or gif ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [library](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom) instead, it's more stable

```js
// just grab a DOM element
const element = document.querySelector('.wrap');

// And pass it to panzoom
panzoom(element);
```

```css
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 60px 20px;
  height: 600px;
}
.wrap .padding, section{
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.7.3/dist/panzoom.min.js'></script>

<div class="wrap">
  
  <div class="padding">
  
    <section>
      <div id="panzoom" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KhWo66L.png" width="100%">
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="buttons">
      <button class="reset">Reset</button>
      <input type="range" class="zoom-range">
    </section>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```